# ASP.Net regular expression validator setting ValidationExpression dynamically

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am trying to do this:

```
<obout:OboutTextBox ID="txtDistributorEmail" runat="server" Width="250" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDistributorEmail" runat="server"     
    ErrorMessage="An invalid email address was entered."                                 
    ValidationExpression='<%=Mynamespace.RegEx.EMAIL %>' 
    ControlToValidate="txtDistributorEmail" />
```

```
namespace Mynamespace
{
    public class RegEx
    {
        public const string EMAIL = @"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z] 
        [-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$";
    }
 }
```

The validation is failing even when a correct email is entered. But if I replace the `ValidationExpression` with the regular expression `[]`, it works fine.

Is there anything in-correct?

Comment: Have a look at how the ValidationExpression is getting rendered in your HTML.  That should tell you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This goes on top of aspx page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Mynamespace" %>
```

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDistributorEmail" runat="server"     
    ErrorMessage="An invalid email address was entered."                                 
    ValidationExpression="<%# Mynamespace.RegEx.EMAIL %>" 
    Display="Dynamic"
    ControlToValidate="txtDistributorEmail" />
```

Comment: Ann, i see this in HTML that's rendered:
revDistributorEmail.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
revDistributorEmail.validationexpression = "<%=RegEx.EMAIL %>";

Comment: oh boy - right click on the .aspx page with that code , then click view source , then the page load part goes in there , not in the HTML   -   or are you using MVC?

Comment: that's what I did. right-click and view source and that's the rendered HTML on the web page.

Comment: Also ur comment earlier doesn't make any sense, the whole idea was not to hard-code the regular expression in the code-behind, but to store them in a class that I can re-use.

Comment: oohhhhh ,   I got it , hold on , I thought you wanted to be able to dynamically change - not reuse , I got it now , hold on

Comment: thanks Scott, but I found is I call it from code-behind it seem to work. Like this:
    protected override void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            base.Page_Load(sender, e);
            revDistributorEmail.ValidationExpression = RegEx.EMAIL;
            this.BindData();

        }

Comment: not sure why it doesn't work if I set it from the .aspx page
ValidationExpression='<%= RegEx.EMAIL%>'

Comment: @KiranD  - this will work the way you wanted it to , just register the namespace at the top of the aspx page

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried:
ValidationExpression="<%# Mynamespace.RegEx.EMAIL %>"
ValidationExpression="<%= Mynamespace.RegEx.EMAIL %>" 
ValidationExpression='<%# Mynamespace.RegEx.EMAIL %>'

Comment: Put the class in App_Code Folder,  that should do it

Answer (score 0):

Try This One; for dynamic `re` validations.

```
RegularExpressionValidator re = new RegularExpressionValidator();
re.ControlToValidate = "textbox121"; //mention your textbox id
re.Style.Add("color", "Red");
re.ID = "Reg1";
re.ValidationExpression = "^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$";
re.ErrorMessage = "Special Characters Are Not Allowed";
```